# Is it possible to start a shell session in a running container (without ssh)

Tags: docker

I was naively expecting this command to run a bash shell in a running container :

```
docker run "id of running container" /bin/bash
```

it looks like it's not possible, I get the error :

```
2013/07/27 20:00:24 Internal server error: 404 trying to fetch remote history for 27d757283842
```

So, if I want to run bash shell in a running container (ex. for diagnosis purposes)

do I have to run an SSH server in it and loggin via ssh ?

Comment: `docker run CONTAINER` is planned in 1.0

Comment: Since docker 1.3 you should really do as described on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26496875/107049)

Comment: just `docker attach container_name`

Comment: It seens like the second answer is much better nowadays than the accepeted one - could you reconsider changing the accepted answer?

Comment: I proposed a separate command `docker shell` https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41702

Answer (score 292, accepted):

EDIT: Now you can use `docker exec -it "id of running container" bash` ([doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/))

Previously, the answer to this question was:

If you really must and you are in a debug environment, you can do this: `sudo lxc-attach -n <ID>`
Note that the id needs to be the full one (`docker ps -notrunc`).

However, I strongly recommend against this.

notice: `-notrunc` is deprecated, it will be replaced by `--no-trunc` soon.

Comment: why do you recommend against it ?

Comment: Here's a use case : I have an nginx server and I want to view logs, the more general use case is having a server that persists working state to files (ex. database) and wanting to view the files or simply view their sizes

Comment: I recommend against it because 1) it requires a very recent kernel, 2) You are doing things outside docker so you won't be able to track it (logs, attach, etc). Also, docker might use lxc right now, but there is no warranty it will do so forever.

Comment: I had been using this solution myself and it had been working brilliantly. Unfortunately I have updated from 0.7.3 to docker 0.7.5 and that no longer seems to be working. Is there an alternative now? Or perhaps "its just me"?

Comment: Try update to 0.7.6. Docker is still using lxc right now and `lxc-attach` should work just fine. I just doubled checked and it works for me. (Note that it won't work with kernel prior 3.8).

Comment: as of 0.9 docker no longer runs with LXC by default. You would have to launch the docker deamon with `docker -d -e lxc`

Comment: Max L., your use case can be resolved with [data volumes](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).
Not tested example:
1) run container with nginx logs in data volume: `docker run -v /var/log/nginx -name somename imagename command`;
2) run another container to view the data volume content: `docker run -volumes-from somename -i -t busybox /bin/sh`.

Answer (score 627):

With docker 1.3, there is a new command [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/). This allows you to enter a running docker:

```
docker exec -it "id of running container" bash
```

Comment: What if I made changes while exec a running container and wanted to reflect the changes online? what is the best practices?

Comment: use ``docker ps`` to get id of running instances

Comment: Note: The container may not have bash (»exec: "bash": executable file not found«). Use `docker inspect <image>` to see what shell is available. E.g. run `docker exec -it <container id> /bin/sh` instead.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 17):

Just do

```
docker attach container_name
```

As mentioned in the comments, to detach from the container without stopping it, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks!! It helped. And in context of the actual question, I would like to add something. After debugging our container using, `docker attach container_name` use `ctrl p` and `ctrl q` instead of `exit`. `exit` command stops the container, where as `ctrlp` and `ctrl q` just detaches that container and keeps it running

Answer (score 10):

Since things are achanging, at the moment the recommended way of accessing a running container is using `nsenter`.

You can find more information on this [github repository](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter). But in general you can use nsenter like this:

```
PID=$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} <container_name_or_ID>)
nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```

or you can use the wrapper `docker-enter`:

```
docker-enter <container_name_or_ID>
```

A nice explanation on the topic can be found on Jérôme Petazzoni's blog entry:
[Why you don't need to run sshd in your docker containers](http://blog.docker.com/2014/06/why-you-dont-need-to-run-sshd-in-docker/)

Comment: unfortunately, env variables are messed up using this approach (if you would like to check variables created by link). I suggest doing `source /proc/*/environ`.

Answer (score 8):

First thing you cannot run

```
docker run "existing container" command
```

Because this command is expecting an *image* and not a *container* and it would anyway result in a new container being spawned (so not the one you wanted to look at)

I agree with the fact that with docker we should push ourselves to think in a different way (so you should find ways so that you don't need to log onto the container), but I still find it useful and this is how I work around it.

I run my commands through supervisor in DEAMON mode.

Then I execute what I call `docker_loop.sh`
The content is pretty much this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/supervisord
/usr/bin/supervisorctl
while ( true )
    do
    echo "Detach with Ctrl-p Ctrl-q. Dropping to shell"
    sleep 1
    /bin/bash
done
```

What it does is that it allows you to "attach" to the container and be presented with the `supervisorctl` interface to stop/start/restart and check logs.
If that should not suffice, you can `Ctrl+D` and you will drop into a shell that will allow you to have a peek around as if it was a normal system.

PLEASE DO ALSO TAKE INTO ACCOUNT that this system is not as secure as having the container without a shell, so take all the necessary steps to secure your container.

Answer (score 5):

Keep an eye on this pull request: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/7409

Which implements the forthcoming `docker exec <container_id> <command>` utility. When this is available it should be possible to e.g. start and stop the ssh service inside a running container.

There is also `nsinit` to do this: *"nsinit provides a handy way to access a shell inside a running container's namespace"*, but it looks difficult to get running.
https://gist.github.com/ubergarm/ed42ebbea293350c30a6

Comment: `docker exec` landed in Docker 1.3, so it is now possible to create and join a new shell session in a running container

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
docker exec -it <container_name> bash
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution

#### In the Dockerfile:

```sh
# ...
RUN mkdir -p /opt
ADD initd.sh /opt/
RUN chmod +x /opt/initd.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/initd.sh"]
```

#### In the `initd.sh` file

```sh
#!/bin/bash
...
/etc/init.d/gearman-job-server start
/etc/init.d/supervisor start
#very important!!!
/bin/bash
```

#### After image is built you have two options using `exec` or `attach`:

1. Use exec (preferred) and run:

   ```sh
   docker run --name $CONTAINER_NAME -dt $IMAGE_NAME
   ```

   then

   ```
   docker exec -it $CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash
   ```

   and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to detach
2. Use attach and run:

   ```sh
   docker run --name $CONTAINER_NAME -dit $IMAGE_NAME
   ```

   then

   ```sh
   docker attach $CONTAINER_NAME
   ```

   and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to detach

   **Note**: The difference between options is in parameter `-i`

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a way to have a shell in the container.

Assume your `/root/run.sh` launches the process, process manager (supervisor), or whatever.

Create `/root/runme.sh` with some gnu-screen tricks:

```
# Spawn a screen with two tabs
screen -AdmS 'main' /root/run.sh
screen -S 'main' -X screen bash -l
screen -r 'main'
```

Now, you have your daemons in tab 0, and an interactive shell in tab 1. `docker attach` at any time to see what's happening inside the container.

Another advice is to create a "development bundle" image on top of the production image with all the necessary tools, including this screen trick.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

With attach

```
$ sudo docker attach 665b4a1e17b6 #by ID
```

With exec

```
$ sudo docker exec - -t 665b4a1e17b6 #by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to check on the application's logs, this post shows starting up tomcat and tailing the log as part of CMD. The tomcat log is available on the host using 'docker logs containerid'.

http://blog.trifork.com/2013/08/15/using-docker-to-efficiently-create-multiple-tomcat-instances/

Answer (score 0):

It's useful assign name when running container. You don't need refer container_id.

`docker run --name container_name yourimage 
docker exec -it container_name bash`

Answer (score 0):

first, get the container id of the desired container by

```
docker ps
```

you will get something like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES
3ac548b6b315        frontend_react-web     "npm run start"     48 seconds ago      Up 47 seconds                   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   frontend_react-web_1
```

now copy this container id and run the following command:

```
docker exec -it container_id sh

docker exec -it 3ac548b6b315 sh
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you were mislead like myself into thinking in terms of VMs when developing containers. My advice: Try not to.

Containers are just like any other process. Indeed you might want to "attach" to them for debugging purposes (think of /proc//env or strace -p ) but that's a very special case.

Normally you just "run" the process, so if you want to modify the configuration or read the logs, just create a new container and make sure you write the logs outside of it by sharing directories, writing to stdout (so docker logs  works) or something like that.

For debugging purposes you might want to start a shell, then your code, then press CTRL-p + CTRL-q to leave the shell intact. This way you can reattach using:

```
docker attach <container_id>
```

If you want to debug the container because it's doing something you haven't expect it to do, try to debug it: https://serverfault.com/questions/596994/how-can-i-debug-a-docker-container-initialization

Comment: This is completely wrong. Being able to introspect the LXC namespace which your application is running in is not a "very special case", it's a common/daily activity for any developer.

Comment: @sleepycal "any developer" sounds a little biased. In any case I do use  introspection of processes so the same thing applies to containers. That's the idea behind debugging. You attach a debugger to the process (which might have a cli). Thinking that you "are" logged in into the container sounds still misleading to me.

Answer (score -4):

No. This is not possible. Use something like `supervisord` to get an ssh server if that's needed. Although, I definitely question the need.