# Docker container does not give me a shell

Tags: linux, bash, docker, containers, dockerfile

I am trying to get a shell inside the Docker container [moul/phoronix-test-suite](https://github.com/moul/docker-phoronix-test-suite) on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/moul/phoronix-test-suite/) using this command

```
docker run -t -i moul/phoronix-test-suite /bin/bash
```

but just after executing the command (binary file), the container stops and I get no shell into it.

```
[slazer@localhost ~]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
0993189463e6        moul/phoronix-test-suite   "phoronix-test-suite "   7 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                       kickass_shockley
```

It is a `ubuntu:trusty` container. How can I get a shell into it, so that I can send arguments to the command phoronix-test-suite?

Comment: Have you tried with an other command? (Try with just sh for instance)

Comment: See: [Is it possible to start a shell session in a running container (without ssh)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17903705/3776858)

Comment: @vmonteco I have tried `/bin/sh` and `/bin/dash`.

Comment: @Cyrus `$ docker exec -it "5556eddf5376" bash` run as user gives me `Error response from daemon: Container long_alphanum_id is not running`

Comment: The status of the container is `Exited (0)`, I should stop the container from exiting after executing `./phoronix-test-suite` in the first place...

Comment: @Slazer What if you try with another image?

Comment: @vmonteco `docker run -it fedora bash` gives me bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker run -t -i moul/phoronix-test-suite /bin/bash` will *not* give you a bash (contrary to `docker run -it fedora bash`)

According to its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/moul/docker-phoronix-test-suite/blob/master/Dockerfile#L13), what it will do is execute

```
phoronix-test-suite /bin/bash
```

Meaning, it will pass `/bin/bash` as parameter to `phoronix-test-suite`, which will exit immediately. That leaves you no time to execute a [`docker exec -it <container> bash`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) in order to open a bash in an active container session.

Comment: Fabulous, thank you. So I have been using it the wrong way, correctly I should type something like `docker run -it moul/phoronix-test-suite detailed-system-info`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried restarting your docker? It might need to restart or even reboot the host.

Comment: I have stopped and removed all containers, the `docker ps -a` and `sudo docker ps -a` now does not show anything. I have even rebooted the machine multiple times. It did not help.

Comment: Follow the link mentioned above and if those steps do not work come back for more brain storming. I will start my docker here and try the commands you are using to figure out where the solution can be found

Comment: Seems like the container is not running, even the status is `Exited (0)`. If you want to brainstorm with me, you better join #docker on irc.freenode.net. I am there.