# How to open multiple terminals in docker?

Tags: docker

I need to launch two distinct processes on a docker container which requires two terminals.What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to start a shell session in a running container (without ssh)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903705/is-it-possible-to-start-a-shell-session-in-a-running-container-without-ssh)

Comment: This is not what the question is about, but rather my reason for finding this question, so it might help others in the future. In VS Code, if you have the Docker extension installed, you can simply right-click the container and attach either a VS Code instance or a terminal.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You can run `docker exec -it <container> bash` from multiple terminals to launch several sessions connected to the same container.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. What if I now want to open up one of the previous interactive terminals that I launched and left running in background and kill it? Using docker ps only shows the container, but if I run ps aux in any of the terminals I see all the ones that I launched.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do this inside a Dockerfile?

Comment: All this assuming that the container features **bash**. In my case I had to go down to **sh**. And pay attention that obviously **the filesystem is the same for all the terminals!!!**

Answer (score 45):

To expand on [@eltonStoneman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4502597/elton-stoneman)'s great answer (For all those new docker folks like me):

1. Open a docker terminal
2. Get the image running as a container in the background: **`docker run -d -it <image_id>`**

- *Tip:* **`docker ps`** *will show the container_id that you just fired up from said image.*

3. Per @eltonStoneman's advice: **`docker exec -it <container_id> bash`**

- *Now your docker terminal is showing an interactive terminal to the container.*

4. Open up another terminal and perform step 3 to create another interactive terminal to the container. *(Rinse and Repeat)*

Comment: Thanks, especially for the `docker ps` bit. BTW, at least on Linux, a normal terminal is fine (doesn't need to be a "docker terminal")

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. What if I now want to open up one of the previous interactive terminals that I launched and left running in background and kill it? Using docker ps only shows the container, but if I run `ps aux` in any of the terminals I see all the ones that I launched.

Answer (score 16):

`docker run -it container_name bash` starts **a new container** with bash promt.

`docker exec -it container_name bash` joins **already running container's** bash prompt.

Answer (score 3):

First get the name of the container 
`docker container ls`
Then get run docker exec command to get in that container
`docker exec <container_id> bash`

Answer (score 1):

Using **Docker Compose**: Let's say you have a Compose yml that enables X-Windows.

You can follow the steps below to launch terminals for a graphic IDE (e.g. qtCreator), nautilus and a terminal window.

*Assumptions:*

- Host is Windows 10. 1803
- Image is Ubuntu Xenial
- Docker engine is 18.03.1-ce
- Docker Compose is 1.21.1
- Windows Xming X Server is 7.7.0.25 - using IPv4 interface 192.168.1.101

*Dockerfile:* Dockerfile-dev-ubuntu_xenial - creates the Docker image

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
LABEL maintainer "Your NAME <your.address@yourmailhost.com>"
RUN apt-get update ; apt-get install -y apt-utils desktop-file-utils dialog nautilus build-essential debhelper fakeroot ccache lsb-release
RUN apt-get install -y autotools-dev autoconf pkg-config libtool curl gedit git wget unzip lintian
RUN apt-get install -y qtcreator valgrind
RUN apt-get install -y sudo \
    && groupadd -r user -g 1000 \
    && useradd -u 1000 -r -g user -m -d /user -s /sbin/nologin -c "Build pkg user" user \
    && chmod 755 /user \
    && echo "user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/user \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/user
WORKDIR /user
USER user
VOLUME ["/buildpkg", "/user/projects", "/user/resources"]
CMD /bin/bash
```

*Compose.yml:* compose-dev-linux.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  # Commands:
  #   Build: docker-compose -f compose-dev-linux.yml build dev_ubuntu_xenial
  #   Up   : docker-compose -f compose-dev-linux.yml up -d dev_ubuntu_xenial
  #   Run  : docker-compose -f compose-dev-linux.yml run dev_ubuntu_xenial
  #   Down : docker-compose -f compose-dev-linux.yml down
  # Host folders:
  #   %USERPROFILE%/Projects
  #   %USERPROFILE%/Projects/Docker-builds
  #   %USERPROFILE%/Projects/Docker-resources
  # Docker configuration file locations:
  #   %USERPROFILE%/Dockerfiles/Dockerfile-dev-ubuntu_xenial
  #   %USERPROFILE%/compose-dev-linux.yml
  dev_ubuntu_xenial:
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=192.168.1.101:0
    network_mode: host
    image: "application-dev-platform/application:ubuntu_xenial"
    container_name: application-dev-ubuntu_xenial
    command: bash -c "/bin/bash"
    tty: true
    build:
      context: ./Dockerfiles
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev-ubuntu_xenial
    volumes:
      - ./Projects:/user/projects
      - ./Projects/Docker-builds:/buildpkg
      - ./Projects/Docker-resources:/user/resources
```

*Run:* - initial Powershell terminal

1. Build image: `docker-compose -f compose-dev-linux.yml build dev_ubuntu_xenial`
2. Launch Docker detached: `docker-compose -f compose-dev-linux.yml up -d dev_ubuntu_xenial`
3. List container(s): `docker ps`
4. Launch container: `docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> bash`
5. Launch qtCreator: `user@linuxkit-<generatedid>:~$ qtcreator`

*Run:* - new Powershell terminal

1. Launch container: `docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> bash`
2. Launch nautilus: `nautilus`

*Run:* - new Powershell terminal

1. Launch container: `docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> bash`
2. Launch terminal: `user@linuxkit-<generatedid>:~$`

Answer (score 1):

first of all I entered below command:

```
docker exec -it <containerName> bash
```

but docker said this container doesn't exist...
after that I replaced containerName with containerID and this trick worked for me;

if you want to know each containers id run below command:

```
sudo docker ps
```

after that run this command to open new terminal to your container:

```
docker exec -it <containerID> bash
```

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I started a container in a terminal (`-i` interactive, `-t` TTY):</sub>

```
docker run -i -t <IMAGE_URL> /bin/bash
```

<sub>My command prompt now starts with `root@484ded1212aa:/` in which `484ded1212aa` is the `CONTAINER ID`.  In another tab (or window) I used that ID:</sub>

```
docker exec -i -t 484ded1212aa /bin/bash
```

<sub>Now both terminal tabs start with `root@484ded1212aa:/` and the second one contains the Git repo that I had cloned in the first terminal (between the above two commands). **This was useful because I wanted to interactively change the code in one tab, and run it in another**.</sub>

<sub>Another way to get the `CONTAINER_ID` or `NAMES` is by the command:</sub>

```
docker container ls
```

<sub>which gives me:</sub>

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
484ded1212aa        registry.gitlab.com/molcas/dockerfiles/gcc-4.8   "/bin/bash"         2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                              hardcore_einstein
```

<sup>Notice that there's still only one container, even though it's open in two tabs.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run **Kitematic** - you can click on **exec** button to open terminal in selected container.

[image]

Comment: He had one problem, now he has two. (run kitematic and then open a new terminal)

Comment: @SparK indeed. Kitematic is now legacy