# How to make multiple independent attachments to the same docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-container

Maybe a trivial question but that's my problem:

I attached to a running docker container, after some use I needed to run a Unit Test and gdb at "the same time".

So I openned another shell tab (konsole tab) and attached again to the same docker container `$ docker attach container_name` but everything I did echoed in both attachments. If I execute `cd /home/user/folder_foo` the other tab will "do the same", ended up both konsole tabs in the same folder. Like the same command was echoed to both tabs. Maybe it's a unique user structure and what I isn't even possible.

I really need to do two thing in parallel in the same docker container, how it could be done?

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.9, build c2ea9bc
```

I am using Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: **I answered this in detail [in this duplicate thread from 5 years earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75062863/1271772).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by using one service per container.
But for development purposes, you can follow mentioned guide.

---

Additionally, there is a similar answer already [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794509/how-to-open-multiple-terminals-in-docker)

> You can run `docker exec -it <container> bash` from multiple terminals to launch several sessions connected to the same container.