# Container captures ports - can I use some kind of router software?

Tags: docker, containers, port

I start a Docker container on my machine. It will have to talk to two services on remote nodes and for this it occupies ports 80 and 443.

I log into the container and start one task from the command line. The task does some initial data exchange with the remote nodes. Having done that, it starts a very long computation without any need to contact the remote nodes anymore.

I'd like to run that task more times in parallel, but I cannot start multiple instances of the container, because they would clash about the ports.

**Is there some kind of software router that I can use to sort out this problem?**

I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794509/how-to-open-multiple-terminals-in-docker) that I can run multiple shells on my container, but I am still curious about the possibility of using a software router to serve multiple containers.

NB: I am not using any docker-compose or kubernetes setting. Just plain, simple containers.

Comment: How does your container accept _inbound_ connections on these ports?

Comment: @DavidMaze Just outbound HTTP requests.

Comment: If you're only making outbound requests, you don't need to "occupy" ports; delete any `docker run -p` or Compose `ports:` options.  These are only needed for inbound requests, and if you delete these options, then there won't be a conflict between multiple containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze - I reckon this is a Docker improvement. I wasn't aware of it. Thank you. Which Docker version introduced this? And again: if my algorithm contained inbound calls, is there a routing solution for running many of them?

Comment: You've only needed published ports for inbound connections at least as long as I've been using Docker, before they switched to date-based release numbers, and before the Docker 1.13 you still very occasionally see in the wild.