# How can I drop into a bash shell with docker-compose?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

**Intention:**
I am trying to figure out how to use the command `docker-compose up --build` to build a machine with an Apache/PHP7.1 service acting as a web server and a MSSQL service as the database for the app that is served from the web server.

I need to be able to type in commands to the docker container while I build this development environment (so that I can look at the PHP logs, etc), but since the web server is running, my terminal is occupied with the output from the web server and when I press `ctrl+Z`, it actually puts the docker process in the background.

**The question:**
Is there anyway that I can run this docker-compose.yml file and have it drop me into the shell on the guest machine?

**Service 1:**

```
webserver:
    image: php:7.1-apache
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 5001:80
```

**Service 2:**

```
mssql:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    depends_on:
      -webserver
```

Comment: The plain `docker` answer applies as well here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17903705/1318694

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) a new process in a running container.

```
docker-compose exec [options] SERVICE COMMAND [ARGS...]
```

In your case

```
docker-compose exec webserver bash
```

The `-i` and `-t` options from `docker exec` are assumed in `docker-compose exec`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, same as `docker run`, `docker-compose` has an option for running the services/containers in the background.

```
docker-compose up --detach --build
```

After that, list the running containers with:

```
docker-compose ps
```

And connect to the container like @Matt already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46615842/7105071).