# Can't run command in terminal to get API connection

Tags: docker, ubuntu, akeneo, pim

I fellow the instruction from official Akeneo Doc. I try to get API connection list.

```
php bin/console pim:oauth-server:list-clients --env=prod
```

Every time I run this command in terminal, it throws error.

> Could not open input file: bin/console

I tried for both version 1.7 and 2.0. It's still same.
Do i need to open terminal in certain folder to run?

Akeneo Server is on docker.

Comment: [The docs say](https://api.akeneo.com/documentation/security.html): "directly on the PIM server". So yes, I think you'll have to [open a shell in the container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17903705/243245) and then find a directory that contains bin/console to run the commands in. It might be obvious, or you could try e.g. `find / -name console`.

Comment: Actually looking at the [Akeneo Docker installation docs](https://docs.akeneo.com/2.3/install_pim/docker/installation_docker.html) you might just be able to `docker exec [container-name] bin/console`

Comment: Thank you. Now i can run. But unfortunately php version is out of date. (i think akeneo needs at least 7.0) i can't update php since i don't have root access.

Answer (score 1):

First I find Id of my container (for me, it's Akeneo)

```
docker container ls
```

my Akeneo Id on docker is

> "0de07xxxxxxx"

I exac my container my this command

```
docker exec -it "0de07xxxxxxx" bash
```

and I find my path folder by find command.

```
find / -name app
```

Now i can run php command to get api connection list. 
and yeah  i do need to open terminal in akeneo folder to run php command lines.